# Windows 10 Sound Level Change suddenly

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, event-log

I asking maybe the same question as many, but the solution I have found that was working for them don't work for me... It's been a long time problem that I wasn't bothering much but it became more and more annoying.

Each time I boot my computer and log on, i get the same sound level that it was when I shut it (10-20), but after like 10-20 second after I am log on, the sound level reset to 45 for no reason. I guess it might be a software or sound driver that make this but like I said, I have test many solution (reinstall driver/changing them/stopping software to start on boot).

Because i don't think people can give me a real solution, I would like to know if in Windows event log(Administrative Tools) there is somewhere that i could listen/see every application that try to change sound level?

Can I find a way to know what is changing the sound level at specific timing?

For what is it :

1. Windows 10 Pro, 1703, 15063.674
2. Motherboard : Asus Z97-Pro
3. Driver : Default Microsoft(before), Realtek(now)
4. Having many "AMD High Difinition Audio Device" "Not plugged in" in Sound->Playback (I dont think its relevant)
5. AMD Card : AMD Radeon R290 (I dont think its relevant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a autohotkey script resetting my volume at launch

```
#Persistent
SetTimer,Loop1,3000
SetTimer,Sub1,100000

Loop1:
SoundGet, master_volume
if master_volume > 30
    SoundSet, 10
Return

Sub1:
ExitApp
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  I think I resolved this issue for myself.  I am on **Dell Precision M3800**.  I have **Windows 10** running. My Audio Driver is **Realtek**.

You have to try two things:

FIRST THING:

1. Go to you "Hidden Icons" tray.
2. Go to your Audio Icon (mine is Dell Audio).
3. In Main tab, Turn off "Speaker Enhancement"
4. Additionally in "Advanced" tab in "Jack Information" I unchecked the "Enable auto popup dialog, when device has been plugged in" (idk
   if this does anything)

SECOND THING:

1. Search system for "Manage Audio Devices"
2. Inside this, click on "Speakers/Headphones" or do the following steps for both.
3. Go to the "Advanced" tab and uncheck "Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device" in the "Exclusive Mode" fieldset.

This worked for me.  Some of it might have been superfluous, but it worked for me.  Lmk if this helped.

Comment: @Maxime4000 did this work?

Comment: Sorry I didn't comment for a while, As I fix my problem by creating a AutoHotKey script launch every boot so if my sound is 45 it's put it back to 10. I can send the script later. Thanks for the answer I will definitively try that when I'm home. :)